# Is it possible to find and recover a Word for Android document?

Tags: files

I have an Acer Iconia B1-A71 which I bought about a year ago, if I remember right. It has Microsoft Word for Android pre-installed. In my naivety I assumed it was a free no-strings-attached app.

Today I was taking a train trip, 2 hours each way, and I thought I'd try using it to work on a fairly large Word document. I sent it to myself via email. Clicking on the .docx attachment started the Word app. It went though an initialization process, but I am very sure that it did not warn me that by using the app I would have to sign up for a Microsoft account and provide permission for Microsoft to access my contacts.

I spent about three hours working on the document during the trip.

When I got home I tried to "share" it by sending it to myself again. What I got was the original unmodified document. Then I tried to "Save as" on the device, and the app crashed or went into a loop, spinning the circular arrow and saying "Working on it". After 4-5 minutes I killed the app.

Now when I start the Word app it demands that I sign up for a free account, and share my contacts with Microsoft. This I refuse to do on principle.

Where I come from this kind of thing is called "bait and switch".

So my question is, is there any way I can find and recover the edited .docx file using File Manager or something (I have tried to find the edited document but can only find the original one), or do I accept that Microsoft has cheated me out of three hours of my time?